# HTML code not loading the data in list box

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating two combo boxes the first one gets loaded initially and up on selecting the text in the combo the second combo box should get filtered. The issue is combo box is not getting loaded.

```
 <html> <head>

    <title> text conversion  </title> <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrepopulateProductName() {   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

            var selectHTML = "";

            var DEV = ["GTXD", "SFGD", "ITXD", "ETXD","CTXD"];
            var SYS = ["GTXS", "ITXS", "ETXS", "CTXS"];
            var ACC = ["GTXA", "ITXA", "ETXA", "CTXA", "SFGA"];

            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            if (document.getElementById("selProductName").value == "DEV") {
               var select = document.getElementById('category').options.length;

               for (var i = 0; i < select; i++) {
                   document.getElementById('category').options.remove(i);
               }

               for (var i = 0; i < DEV.length; i++) {
                   var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
                   selectHTML = "<option value='" + DEV[i] + "'>" + DEV[i] + "</option>";
                   newSelect.innerHTML = selectHTML;
                   document.getElementById('category').add(newSelect);
               }
           }

           PrepopulateProductName();

       </script> </head> <body>

        Product Name: <select id="selProductName" name="selProductName"
        onchange="changeProductName(this.value);">   <option>--Choose Product
        Name--</option> </select>

    </body> </html>
```

Comment: On a side note, you're missing the closing `}` in your function

Answer (score 1):

There were few issues in your code:

1. You didn't define the `category` select box
2. Called an undefined function `changeProductName()`

This is what you can do:

With the `onchange` attribute, call the `PrepopulateProductName()` function. Then, it will check for the selected option and populate the `category` select box with the values defined.

Example:

```js
function PrepopulateProductName() {

            //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");

            var selectHTML = "";

            var DEV = ["GTXD", "SFGD", "ITXD", "ETXD","CTXD"];
            var SYS = ["GTXS", "ITXS", "ETXS", "CTXS"];
            var ACC = ["GTXA", "ITXA", "ETXA", "CTXA", "SFGA"];

            //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            if (document.getElementById("selProductName").value == "DEV") {
             var select = document.getElementById('category').options.length;

             for (var i = 0; i < select; i++) {
                 document.getElementById('category').options.remove(i);
             }

             for (var i = 0; i < DEV.length; i++) {
                 var newSelect = document.createElement('option');
                 selectHTML = "<option value='" + DEV[i] + "'>" + DEV[i] + "</option>";
                 newSelect.innerHTML = selectHTML;
                 document.getElementById('category').add(newSelect);
             }
         }
     }
```

```html
 <html> <head>

    <title> text conversion  </title> 

</head> 
<body>

    Product Name: <select id="selProductName" name="selProductName"
    onchange="PrepopulateProductName();">   <option>--Choose Product
    Name--</option> <option value="DEV">DEV</option> </select>

    <select id="category" name="category">  </select>
</body> </html>
```